# Why there are nearly no upper wing jetliners?

Tags: airliner, wing, antonov-225, soviet-union, tupolev

Whenever I look at the western airliners. All of their wings are always mounted on the lower part of the fuselage except the Dash 8 series which have turbo props.

But the Soviet jetliners have their wings on the top of their fuselage like the Antonov AN-158

My guess is they are mounted on the bottom because it makes reaching the engines possible and even the Soviet planes are designed to be few meters above the ground to make it easier to access the engines just like the western Dash 8 planes [maybe it's a coincidence because they don't make big airliners and dash 8 planes are small]

Is there an reason why nearly all jetliners have bottom mounted wings?

Comment: Don't forget the [Avro RJ-85 / RJ-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146)

Comment: Dash 6, ATR 42/72, Short Skyvan/330/360, CASA C-212/235/295, Let L-410, Lockheed L-100...

Comment: I suspect the Russian planes, like military jet transports, have their engines mounted high to help protect them from ingesting dirt &c when they land on unimproved strips.  That's seldom a consideration for western commercial airliners.

Comment: @jamesqf -- yeah, the Tupolev Tu-204/214 are the only low-wing Russian jetliners I can think of with wing-mounted engines